# Switch the insides of two Arrays in C

Tags: c

How can I swap the insides of two arrays ?

For example:

```
a [] = {1,2,3,4}
b [] = {5,6,7,8,9}

a'[]= {5,6,7,8,9}
b'[] = {1,2,3,4}
```

Of course these arrays need an `int` and bla bla bla but is there a formula that can switch those two arrays ?

```
int main(){

    int a [6] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int b [6] = {6,7,8,9,10,11};
    int x[7] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0} ; 
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int v = 0;
    printf("Array A : ");
    
    while(i<=4){
        printf("%d ",a[i] );
        i++;
    }
    
    printf("\nArray B:");
    
    while (j<=5){ // ofc its not working and was just a thought but ...

        printf("%d ", b[j]);
        j++;
    } 

    int k = 0;
    while (v <= 6){
        a[k] = x[k];
        b[k] = a[k]; 
        x[k] = b[k];
        v++;
        k++;
    }
    
    printf("\nNeues Array A : ");
    int z = 0;
    int l = 0; 
    
    while(z<=4){
        printf("%d ",a[i] );
        z++;
    }
    
    printf("\nNeues Array B:");
    
    while (l<=5){
        printf("%d ", b[j]);
        l++;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use pointers to point to different arrays throughout the lifetime in your program, but arrays in C are fixed-size, so actually exchanging the contents of two differently-sized arrays is not possible.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but why are you using `while` loops and many different variables to loop over the arrays? The common way is to use a `for` loop, where you define the index variable in the loop itself, like for example `for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; ++i) { ... }`. Then you can also use the same variable name `i` for all your loops.

Comment: In the loops with `z` and `l`, you use `z` or `l` as loop counter, but print `a[i]` or `b[j]`. So, you print the same value 5 or 6 times

Comment: You have a problem with the order here `a[k] = x[k]; b[k] = a[k];`. Since `x` is all zeroes you're overwriting the value in `a` then `b` with `0`. Normally to swap you'd want `int temp = a[k]; a[k] = b[k]; b[k] = temp;` Obviously only arrays of equal size can be swapped like this.

Comment: Assuming all the other problems were solved, your "swap" is basically: `a = x; b = a; x = b;`. Write down some values with a pencil and see if this works or not.

Answer (score 1):

The sound way to swap arrays in C is often *not* to swap the actual arrays.

Instead do something like this:

```
int buf1 [6] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int buf2 [6] = {6,7,8,9,10,11};
int* a = buf1;
int* b = buf2;
```

Then just swap the pointers:

```
int* tmp = a;
a = b;
b = tmp;
```

The advantage of using pointers is flexibility and performance. I've lost count over how many times I've reviewed real-time critical code such as an embedded systems interrupt service routine that fills up some buffer. Then instead of just swapping pointers, the programmer stalls the whole program to do a needlessly slow hard copy of the buffer. Don't copy data unless you actually have to.

Answer (score 0):

The least boilerplate-y way to do it if memory is not an issue is:

```c
int tmp[6];
memcpy(tmp, a, sizeof(a));
memcpy(a, b, sizeof(a));
memcpy(b, tmp, sizeof(a));
```

Just be sure all 3 arrays are the same size.